# List of all top level domains

Tags: url, tld, country-codes

I found a lot of threads explaining how to get the country-codes in two- or three-letter format, but nothing that fits to my task.
I'm heading for a way to get all the top level domains in an array or something. I know there's the CultureInfo class in C# but which could list the country codes. It doesn't include generic TLD, e.g.: "com". [Here's the complete list of country codes I found](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/websoft/wwwstat/country-codes.txt).

Comment: Do you mean top level domain names (TLDs)? Both the two-letter geographical TLDs and the non-geographical ones?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the top level domain names. And yes, I need to get the geographical ones and the other ones.

Comment: Note: `.com` is *not* a country-code top-level domain (ccTLD), but a generic top-level domain (gTLD).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The authoritative list of all TLDs: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

> The Root Zone Database represents the delegation details of top-level domains, including gTLDs such as `.com`, and country-code TLDs such as `.uk`.

You can get this as TXT, too (easier to parse): http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

---

Wikipedia also lists all TLDs, but it's not authoritative, of course: [List of Internet top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)

---

The Mozilla Foundation maintains a [Public Suffix List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List) for *effective* top-level domains, i.e., those under which you can directly register names (for example `.co.uk` instead of `.uk`): http://publicsuffix.org/

Comment: See also [tldextract](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract), which handles this problem very well and uses Mozilla's PSL, as pointed out by @unor. It is in Python, but you may be able to glean the way it handles certain cases from its source code. (A win, because the problem domain is full of nuisances.)

Comment: the txt file only lists the TLDs but not whether they are country-codes or not. Do you know of a list that either provides this information or lists just TLDs of country-codes?

Comment: @IttayD: In case you missed it: the first link contains a table with the column "Type", where it says "country-code" for ccTLDs.

Comment: @unor: i didn't miss, but parsing html is a pain

Answer (score 11):

I like to use this list (it includes private TLDs): http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1. To me it's the most complete list I could find and it's in a plain text format.

Comment: A lot more useful, since it includes TLDs like .co.uk etc

Comment: Looks like the link is dead now unfortunately.