# Create sub sub domains, URL with two subdomains

Tags: url, web, subdomain

If i have a site with url www.example.com, is possible to have another subdomain with the subdomain www? for example www.extra.example.com. I don't sure about this.

I tried to find some information, but i don't have enough experience in that area

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`qux.bar.foo.example.com`

`com` is the top-level domain,
`example` is the second-level domain,
`foo` is the third-level domain,
`bar` is the fourth-level domain,
`qux` is the fifth-level domain.

And yes, you can have more levels (DNS calls them "labels").

Many people mean only the third-level domain when they say "subdomain" (or fourth-level domain in case of an [*effective* top-level domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444138/1591669) like `co.uk`), probably because most domains don’t have more levels, however:

`foo` is the subdomain of `example.com`,
`bar` is the subdomain of `foo.example.com`,
`qux` is the subdomain of `bar.foo.example.com`.

By the way, [`www` is no special label, just a convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26092914/1591669).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. In your example, the two sub-domains "www" and "www.extra" are different.

Comment: But, the whole "www.extra" is a subdomain? Or is it a sub sub domain? some hosting services has restrictions for the subdomain www. Is possible anyway have two subdomains?

Comment: Well strictly anything in front of the domain is a sub-domain. The RFC doesn't add any restrictions and there is no requirement to use (or not use) www, that is just common convention. But you are right, some services apply unnecessary restrictions that may prevent certain combinations. But you can absolutely have as many sub-domains as you like, that is the whole point. Those can point to the same or a different physical location as you want. It is a very flexible approach.

Comment: Your domain is `example.com` and `www` is a sub domain.