# Is accurate uri parsing impossible?

Tags: web, url, uri

Let's just look at the **host** part, since subdomain can have unlimited levels, and there can be a different level of domains, for example:

```
foo.foo2.host.bar.bar2
```

This is a completely valid host, but while the below are also valid:

```
foo.foo2.foo3.host.bar.bar2
foo.foo2.host.bar.bar2.bar3
```

Basically, we can't really use the 'dot' to tell the difference between subdomains and domains

So without a network to actually look up the domain info from the web, is it impossible to properly parse a URI?

How does a web browser handle this situation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Why does it matter whats a subdomain and what is not? By the way, everything but the last part is a subdomain, the last part is a top level domain.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology:

- In the HTTPS URI `https://m.example.com/foo`, the [host](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) component is `m.example.com` (which is a "registered name").
- In the registered name `m.example.com`, `com` is the top-level domain, `example` is the second-level domain, and `m` is the third-level domain. In DNS, each of these levels is [called *label*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26092914/1591669).
- The third-level domain (and fourth-level etc.) is typically called *subdomain*.
- The term *domain* can refer to different things:
- the whole thing (`m.example.com`)
- the combination of top-level and second-level (`example.com`), possibly including additional levels (in case it’s a [public suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444138/1591669), like `co.uk`)

When you want to parse the registered name `m.example.com` (or as FQDN: `m.example.com.`), you go **from right to left**; each label is separated by a `.`:

1. The first label is the top-level domain (`com`)
2. The second label is the second-level domain (`example`)
3. The third label is the third-level domain (`m`)